# How to disable multiple TapGestures from being recognized simultaneously in SwiftUI List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to build a simple List in SwiftUI, each row will perform an action on tap, here's a sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(1..<10) { i in
        Text("Hello, world!")
          .onTapGesture {
            print("Tapped: ", i)
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works, however, if user multi-taps on two rows, the console is going to print twice. Not great if I'm pushing a secondary view controller. Is there a way to have some sort of `exclusiveTouch` property to each List item similar to what was available in UIKit?

Answer (score -3):

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(1..<10) { i in
        Text("Hello, world!")
        if (1..<3) {
/////
        }else {
          .onTapGesture {
            print("Tapped: ", i)
          }
        }
         
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer my question. How does this answer prevent multiple touches from happening on my List?